# Как скачать файл в нужную директорию?

Tags: java, android, android-wear

Как мне быть, если я использую этот код, то соответственно файл загружается в дерикторию `download`, а мне нужно скачать файл в дерикторию `/data/app/` для того чтобы на часах запустилась автоматическая установка цыферблата

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setTitle(apkName);
        request.setDescription("Downloading " + apkName);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, outputFileName);
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Перенесите файл после скачивания, иначе похоже никак: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541423/5479247

Comment: Там говорится совсем о другом, а именно о том как скачать файл во внутреннее хранилище приложения